# Solving the$\underset{[0,{\pi}]\times[0,{\pi}]}{\iint}{\cos}{(x+y)}dxdy$ with change of variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

so I need to solve the following integral using some change of variables:

$$\underset{[0,{\pi}]\times[0,{\pi}]}{\iint}{\cos}{(x+y)}dxdy$$

It's easy without a change of variables, of course, but any suggestion as to how to do it **with** a change of variables?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried $u=x+y$ and $v=y$?

Comment: ... Then Fubini, and then  for the variable $v$ with the "destroyed interval", note that its "distroyed length" still adds to $\pi$ from the pieces.

Comment: For some reason when I use that a get a wrong answer: $\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}{{\cos}{u}}{dudv}$, which is zero. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong there...

Comment: Oh nevermind, the limits of my integral are obviously wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just swap x and y? It is a change of variables.

Answer (score 4):

Use the substitution
$$\left.\eqalign{x&=u  \cr y&=v-u\cr} \ \right\}\qquad\bigl((u,v)\in P: \ 0\leq u\leq\pi , \  \ u\leq v\leq u+\pi\bigr)\ .$$
Its Jacobian determinant is $\equiv1$. Therefore you get
$$\eqalign{\int_{[0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]}\cos(x+y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)&=\int_P\cos v\>{\rm d}(u,v)=\int_0^\pi\int_u^{u+\pi}\cos v\>dv\>du\cr  &=\int_0^\pi-2\sin u\>du=-4\ .\cr}$$